# Parsing form data / multi-part requests with Pythons WSGI

Tags: python, wsgi, multipartform-data, form-data

Is there a recommendable library to parse form data and/or multi-part requests with Python and WSGI?

Comment: WSGI defines an interface between a web application and a webserver. It has nothing to do with what you do in your application. The `email` package can parse multi-part mime messages. But most web frameworks have a more lightweight form parser built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cgi.FieldStorage to parse form posts etc.

You may be better off though using Werkzeug/Flask which has its own implementation which works a lot better, plus you get higher level stuff which makes things a lot easier.

Comment: My choice is Flask. Looks really good and saves me a lot of time.